# Formatting grabbed data from dropdwon boxes and adding data into the result in Python Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, webrequest

I have the following code that partially runs but with a very messy result display. I need help on how to get the additional data as well formatting of the output.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re, random, ctypes
import requests, os
from time import sleep
import beepy as beep
from time import strftime
import datetime

user_agent_list = [
"header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0'}",
"header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'}",
"header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15'}",
"header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36'}",
"header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36'}",
"header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.67 Safari/537.36'}"
]
header = random.choice(user_agent_list)

line = "https://bscscan.com/address/0x639AD7c49EC616a64e074c21a58608C0d843A8a3"
contractpage = requests.get(line,header)
ca = BeautifulSoup(contractpage.content, 'html.parser')
contractcreator = ca.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_trContract').get_text()

tokenname = ca.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_tokeninfo').get_text()
transcount = ca.find('p', class_='mr-2 mb-2').get_text()
tokencount = ca.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_tokenbalance').get_text()

print (contractcreator)
print ("Token Name: ", tokenname)
print ("Trans Count: ", transcount)
print ("Token Count: ", tokencount)
```

Current Output: #-- very, very messy with some intended data missing

```
ContractCreator:
0x7ab96edb99e1faa06238609947792038520f1a3c at txn 0x51a8db6ac707dcd9644b5400b533c9bbe95243054c9c67e8a8aeeab38c7f7e79

Token Name:  
TokenTracker:
 TripCandy (CANDY)
Trans Count:  
 Latest 25 from a total of 2,878 transactions

Token Count:  
Token:
$726.10
3

Could not find any matches! Token display limit reached. Click to Show more

 BEP-20 Tokens (3)    Minereum BSC (MNEB)150,000 MNEB Neftipedia (NFT)1 NFT$0.01@0.0086TripCandy (CANDY)76,581.46551862 CANDY$726.09@0.0095
```

Wanted Output:   #-- current data extracted when I run the code

```
ContractCreator: 0x7ab96edb99e1faa06238609947792038520f1a3c
Txn:             0x51a8db6ac707dcd9644b5400b533c9bbe95243054c9c67e8a8aeeab38c7f7e79
Token Name:      TripCandy (CANDY)
Trans Count:     2,875
Balance:         0.498586644749540253 BNB #-- needed additional data
Tokens ValCount: $732.78 / 3              #-- needed additional data and formatting
Token List:      BEP-20 Tokens (3)        #-- data from the dropdown box
                 Minereum BSC (MNEB)150,000 MNEB
                 Neftipedia (NFT)1                - $0.01 @ 0.0086
                 TripCandy (CANDY)76,581.46551862 - $732.77 @ 0.0096
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pp

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0'
}

adds = [
    '0x639AD7c49EC616a64e074c21a58608C0d843A8a3'
]


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        for add in adds:
            r = req.get(url.format(add))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
            goal = soup.select('div.card-body')
            data = {
                'ContractCreator': goal[1].select_one('a.hash-tag').text,
                'Txn': goal[1].select('a.hash-tag')[1].text,
                'Token Name': goal[1].select('a')[3].text,
                'Trans Count': soup.select_one('p.mr-2 a').text,
                'Balance': goal[0].select_one('.col-md-8').get_text(strip=True),
                'Tokens ValCount': " / ".join(list(goal[0].select_one('.position-relative').stripped_strings)[:2]),
                'Token List': [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in soup.select('.list.list-unstyled strong, .list-name')]
            }
            pp(data)


main('https://bscscan.com/address/{}')
```

Output:

```
{'ContractCreator': '0x7ab96edb99e1faa06238609947792038520f1a3c',
 'Txn': '0x51a8db6ac707dcd9644b5400b533c9bbe95243054c9c67e8a8aeeab38c7f7e79',    
 'Token Name': 'TripCandy (CANDY)',
 'Trans Count': '2,880',
 'Balance': '0.498586644749540253 BNB',
 'Tokens ValCount': '$727.19 / 3',
 'Token List': ['BEP-20 Tokens',
                'Minereum BSC (MNEB)',
                'Neftipedia (NFT)',
                'TripCandy (CANDY)']}
```

Comment: Im learning python as part of my work, Im not an IT guy. Thank you for your answer. I found a way to get around.