# How to grab the first 10 table data in my python beautifulsoup code snippet

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to find ways to grab additional data from a page. I am able to extract some parts but I cannot make the table data extract to work.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, random, re

header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
url = "https://bscscan.com/token/"
suffix = "#balances"

token = "0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3"    

line = str(url) + str(token) + str(suffix)
urlpage = requests.get(line,header)
ca = BeautifulSoup(urlpage.content, 'html.parser')

tokenholders = ca.find(id='ContentPlaceHolder1_tr_tokenHolders').get_text()
totalholders = ((((tokenholders.strip()).strip("Holders:")).strip()).strip(" a ")).strip()
caname = ca.find('span', class_='text-secondary small').get_text()

def get_transfer_count(str:token)->str:
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
        r = s.get(f'https://bscscan.com/token/{token}')
        pause = float(random.randint(10,100)) / 200
        sid = re.search(r"var sid = '(.*?)'", r.text).group(1)
        r = s.get(f'https://bscscan.com/token/generic-tokentxns2?m=normal&contractAddress={token}&a=&sid={sid}&p=1')
        return re.search(r"var totaltxns = '(.*?)'", r.text).group(1)
transfers = get_transfer_count(token)
print (f"{caname}:     {totalholders} -> {transfers}")

#-- extracting table data is not working. 
print (line)
reqblockdetails = requests.get(line,header, timeout=5)
soupblockdetails = BeautifulSoup(reqblockdetails.content, 'html.parser')
rowsblockdetails = soupblockdetails.findAll('table')[1].findAll('tr', limit=10)

for row in rowsblockdetails[1:]:
    rank = row.find_all('tr')[1].text[0:]
    address = row.find_all('tr')[2].text[0:]
    percentage = row.find_all('tr')[3].text[0:]
    print (f"{rank} {address}  {percentage}")
```

Current Output:

```
https://bscscan.com/token/0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3#balances
SafeMoon:     2,539,065 -> 8,572,618
```

Wanted Output:

```
https://bscscan.com/token/0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3#balances
SafeMoon:     2,539,065 -> 8,572,618
1   0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001  422,608,339,470,158.650668327   42.2608%    $1,119,912,099.60   
2   0x8c128dba2cb66399341aa877315be1054be75da8  37,990,543,914,353.982959304    3.7991%     $100,674,941.37 
3   0xa8736b9585a01d6dcc1b6e2fc9dc208552c34b58  20,000,000,001,566.132214712    2.0000%     $53,000,000.00  
4   PancakeSwap: SAFEMOON                       14,683,889,881,691.961615175    1.4684%     $38,912,308.19  
5   0xff3dd404afba451328de089424c74685bf0a43c9  14,420,512,875,428.18524578     1.4421%     $38,214,359.12
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting grabbed data from dropdwon boxes and adding data into the result in Python Beautifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68614389/formatting-grabbed-data-from-dropdwon-boxes-and-adding-data-into-the-result-in-p)

Comment: I was hoping that was an answer. Any help or ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That table is present inside an `<iframe>` and therefore you cannot see the table in the current soup.

This is the URL of the `<iframe>`

```
https://bscscan.com/token/generic-tokenholders2?m=normal&a=0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3&s=1000000000000000000000000&sid=68a003f6aa7123d1ce19faee148486b1&p=1
```

You have to make a request to this URL, scrape and get the tabular data.

Here is the Code that prints the first 10 entries of the table

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://bscscan.com/token/generic-tokenholders2?m=normal&a=0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3&s=1000000000000000000000000&sid=68a003f6aa7123d1ce19faee148486b1&p=1'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
t = soup.find('table', class_='table table-md-text-normal table-hover')
trs = t.find('tbody').find_all('tr')
for tr in trs[:10]:
    print(list(tr.stripped_strings))
```

Output:

```
['1', '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001', '422,615,749,763,257.513764866', '42.2616%', '$1,132,610,209.37']
['2', '0x8c128dba2cb66399341aa877315be1054be75da8', '37,999,291,994,662.389545005', '3.7999%', '$101,838,102.55']
['3', '0xa8736b9585a01d6dcc1b6e2fc9dc208552c34b58', '20,000,000,001,566.132214712', '2.0000%', '$53,600,000.00']
['4', 'PancakeSwap: SAFEMOON', '14,597,898,747,034.97164353', '1.4598%', '$39,122,368.64']
['5', '0xff3dd404afba451328de089424c74685bf0a43c9', '14,338,244,183,795.067059958', '1.4338%', '$38,426,494.41']
['6', '0x79c4af7c43f500b9ccba9396d079cc03dfcafda1', '12,606,343,926,481.050930218', '1.2606%', '$33,785,001.72']
['7', '0x86b695aaa2600668cec754c7827357626b188054', '10,296,425,935,389.814451821', '1.0296%', '$27,594,421.51']
['8', 'Safemoon Protocol: Deployer', '7,734,340,607,205.689408066', '0.7734%', '$20,728,032.83']
['9', '0xdbe831064ae9b8646de09f270eef3f0076ce9def', '7,384,872,027,653.233402227', '0.7385%', '$19,791,457.03']
['10', '0x82b7503bffd8aea31aea5ee14fb01959191af45b', '5,238,068,028,741.773442656', '0.5238%', '$14,038,022.32']
```

Comment: How did you get the https://bscscan.com/token/generic-tokenholders2?m=normal&a=0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3&s=1000000000000000000000000&sid=68a003f6aa7123d1ce19faee148486b1&p=1

Comment: I have mentioned that the table is part of an iframe, this URL is the source of that iframe. You can see that in the HTML code of your URL.